# Cambiar orden de párrafos - Cambiar orden de elementos jQuery

Tags: jquery

Este es el texto que deseo tratar, está englobado en un `body` y a su vez cada dentro de un `div` llamado "contenido", en el cual existen varios `párrafos`. Mi idea es **intercambiar un párrafo por otro**, es decir que el párrafo llamado "segundoparrafo" pase a ser el "tercerparrafo" y al revés.

**¿Cómo podría realizarse?** En la documentación de jQuery pone lo siguiente en la Manipulación de elementos:

```
// hacer que el primer item de la lista sea el último
var $li = $('#myList li:first').appendTo('#myList');

// otro enfoque para el mismo problema
$('#myList').append($('#myList li:first'));
```

Código del HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div class="contenido" id="contenido" style="width:80%;height:100%;background-color:#e8e8e8;min-height:900px;margin:auto;">
            <h2 style="margin-left:30px;">Parrafos del texto</h2>

            <p class="alert">
                Utiliza los botones inferiores para que utilizando jquery se hagan los efectos que se indican.
            </p>


            <p class="segundoparrafo">
                Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse <strong>molestie</strong> 
                consequat, vel illum <strong>dolore</strong>eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim 
                qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                consectetuer <strong>adipiscing</strong> elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
            </p>


            <p class="tercerparrafo">
                Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
                <em style="color: rgb(153, 51, 0); font-weight: bold;">commodo</em> consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in 
                <em style="color: rgb(153, 51, 0); font-weight: bold;">vulputate</em>velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla 
                facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blan dit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te <strong>feugait</strong> 
                nulla facilisi.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Quieres cambiar el orden en que se muestran o intercambiar el contenido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hago un `if` que compruebe que el siguiente elemento a `.alert` sea el `segundoparrafo`.

Si lo es, pongo el tercero delante del segundo.
Si no lo es, pongo el segundo delante del tercero.

```js
$("#cambiar").click(function() {

  if ($(".alert").next().attr('class') == "segundoparrafo") {

    $(".segundoparrafo").before($(".tercerparrafo"));

  } else {

    $(".segundoparrafo").after($(".tercerparrafo"));

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body> <input type="button" id="cambiar" value="cambiar">
  <div class="contenido" id="contenido" style="width:80%;height:100%;background-color:#e8e8e8;min-height:900px;margin:auto;">
    <h2 style="margin-left:30px;">Parrafos del texto</h2>

    <p class="alert">
      Utiliza los botones inferiores para que utilizando jquery se hagan los efectos que se indican.
    </p>


    <p class="segundoparrafo">
      Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse <strong>molestie</strong> consequat, vel illum <strong>dolore</strong>eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum
      zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer <strong>adipiscing</strong> elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </p>


    <p class="tercerparrafo">
      Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
      <em style="color: rgb(153, 51, 0); font-weight: bold;">commodo</em> consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in
      <em style="color: rgb(153, 51, 0); font-weight: bold;">vulputate</em>velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blan dit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis
      dolore te <strong>feugait</strong> nulla facilisi.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```